# Unable to send request via $http(AJAX) in angularjs service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to send request via $http(AJAX) in my service for user session exist or not. But it not get any result.

Code:-

```
eshopApp.service('userDataService', function ($rootScope,$http) {


 $http({
    method: "POST",
    url: "services/login.php"
  }).success(function (response) {
    if (response.status == 'SUCCESS') {
        $rootScope.userData = response.userdata;
    }
    console.log($rootScope.userData);
  }).error(function (error) {
    alert('Unable to login. Please try later.');
 });
});
```

I am novice in angularjs. If there any mistake please ignorance.

Comment: Check the error message in your error call back that will be available in error object. Also on dev console check for the errors.

Answer (score 1):

At first check your **response**

console.log(response);

and check what value get in your `response`

if `response.status` value is *SUCCESS* then check

```
if (response.status === 'SUCCESS')
```

instead of `if(response.status == 'SUCCESS')`

and ensure that you have data in `response.userdata`

**N.B:** The `==` operator will compare for equality after doing necessary *type conversions*. If use `===` operator *no need* to *type conversion*. 
so if two values are not the same type `===` will return false.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I generally format mine.

```
$http.post('services/login.php', POST-DATA-GOES-HERE-IF-ANY)
.success(function(response){
    if (response.status === 'SUCCESS') {
        $rootScope.userData = response.userdata;
    }
    console.log($rootScope.userData);
}).error(function (error) {
    alert('Unable to login. Please try later.');
});
```

Note: Three '=' instead of two.
Note: I'd console log the response til you've got it functioning correctly.

Hopefully this works for you :D